# Can't connect Linkedin with Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, linkedin-api

My problem is that i'm trying import date user from Linkedin to my user Drupal. After setting secret keys i try to connect to Linkedin, then Linkedin show me your login interface, but i try to confirm, not redirect to my home but to apper a 404 page. I dont know what is my problem, if the problem is from Linkedin, from my server or from me.

Comment: It is probably due to your linkedin application settings, check the callback url and make sure it redirects back to an existing page on your website.

Comment: I forgot tell about this, i configure in linkedin application that  redirect is my home page.